# Compare properties in request if they have equal value C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I want to compare if the properties in the request have the same value. I have the following json that I use for request via PostMan.

```
“request”:[ {
“Id”: “1234567”,
“Position”: “1”,
“IsSet”: true
},
{
“Id”: “1234587”,
“Position”: “1”,
“IsSet”: true
}, 
]
```

In the code I want to compare if properties Position and IsSet has the same value foreach id in the request. If they don’t to throw error.

```
public class Info
{
     public string Id {get; set;}
     public string Position {get; set;}
     public bool IsSet {get; set;}
}
```

I have method called Validate to validate those properties.

```
public class Validate(Info context)
{
    foreach (var item in context)
    {
        // what code should check this
    }
}
```

Comment: So I guess `Validate` should be a method and not a class? And the method should take a `List<Info>` as arguement instead of `Info`.

Comment: Yes , that is right!

Comment: Is it always 2 items in the array or can me numerous?

Comment: No, they can be numerous.

Comment: @JessikaParker Answer below will account for any scenario. My question is obsolete sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQs `Select` and `Distinct` for that purpose.

Here's a sample `"Validate"` method.

```
List<Test> objs = new List<Test>()
    {
        new Test(){ Position = "random position 1", IsSet = true, Id = 123 },
        new Test(){ Position = "random position 2", IsSet = true, Id = 123 },
        new Test(){ Position = "random position 3", IsSet = true, Id = 123 }

    };

    if(objs.Count() > 1){
        var query = objs.Select(p => new { p.Id, p.IsSet }).Distinct();

        var allTheSame = query.Count() == 1;

        Console.WriteLine(allTheSame);
    }else{

        Console.WriteLine("Nothing To Compare Against");    
    }
}
```

The logic here is to check if there's more than 1 item in the list - just so we know there's something to compare the values against.

If more than one, select the properties you want to match objects on and call distinct on it.

Then we get the count of the distinct values, if they all match we will always get 1 returned from the `query.Count()` hence the boolean check.

At this point if `allTheSame` is `false` you can throw your error instead of the `Console.WriteLine`

In the second `Console.WriteLine` you can always return true since there's nothing to compare making it distinct enough.

Here's a sample [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQJlnC).

Answer (score 2):

I like Adriani6's answer. But it works only with simple classes. Best solution i think is Equals method. You can easy generate it with Resharper (Alt+insert, Equaliti members):

```
public class Info
    {
        protected bool Equals(Info other)
        {
            return string.Equals(Id, other.Id) && string.Equals(Position, other.Position) && IsSet == other.IsSet;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((Info) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = (Id != null ? Id.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Position != null ? Position.GetHashCode() : 0);
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ IsSet.GetHashCode();
                return hashCode;
            }
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public bool IsSet { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply step through your list in your Validation method with a nested loop.
Assuming it's an IEnumerable like an array or List you could do the following:

```
// not a class, context is IEnumerable, not a single entitry
// Returns true if OK, false if any element is not the same.
// 'Sameness' (equality) defined in Info-class as implemented by IEquatable
public bool Validate(IEnumerable<Info> context)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < context.Count(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < context.Count(); j++)
        {
            if (!context[i].Equals(context[j])) {return false;}
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And Info with [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public class Info : IEquatable<Info>
{
    protected bool Equals(Info other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Id, other.Id) && string.Equals(Position, other.Position) && IsSet == other.IsSet;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Info) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (Id != null ? Id.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (Position != null ? Position.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ IsSet.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public bool IsSet { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to be fancy you can overload == and != operators like so:

```
public static bool operator ==(Info lhs, Info rhs) { return lhs.Equals(rhs); }
public static bool operator !=(Info lhs, Info rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
```